# Difference between `this.$store.state.someField = value` vs updating state with commit or dispatch in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js

I read the doc and know that the official recommendation is to use `mutation` to change the sate. But what the document does not explain (or that I did not understand) is what is the difference between the two/three ways.

---

Can I update the state of the store with `store.state.someField=xyz`? What is the difference between doing it this way and using `commit` or `dispatch`?

Answer (score 3):

If you set the state in that way, state changes could be unpredictable and untraceable, when your application grows.
That's why vuex standardized it as 4 different state management steps.

1)state
2)mutations
3)actions
4)getters

So here in your case, you can categorize like this

```
 state: {
      someField
  },


mutations: {
    UPDATE_DATA(state, newValue) {
      state.someField= newValue;
    },

 actions: {
    updateData({commit}, newValue) {
      commit('UPDATE_DATA',newValue);
    },

 getters: {
    filedValue: state => {
      return state.someField;
    }
```

And from the component where you want to set the value, you can dispatch like this.

```
 this.$store.dispatch('updateData', 'testvalue');
```